# Ansible handler using if statements

Tags: ansible, ansible-handlers

I have an apache playbook which needs to run on centos 7 and centos 6. I want the handler triggered based on distribution major version. I have a handler called `restart apache on 7` and another one `restart apache on 6`.

My `handlers/main.yml` looks like this

```
 ---
 - name: restart apache on 7
  systemd: name=httpd state=restarted

 - name: restart apache on 6
   service: name=httpd state=restarted
```

I have tried doing the following in my `tasks/main.yml`but seem to be running into syntax issues pertaining to the notify script.

```
- name: Copy custom configs
  copy:
   dest: /etc/httpd/conf/
   src: httpd.conf
   owner: root 
  notify: {%if ansible_distribution_major_version >= '7.0' %}restart apache on 7 {%else%} restart apache on 6 {%endif%}
```

Any clues on how to write the notify statement to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3):

For a general solution, you can use [topics](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_handlers.html#naming-handlers), but I'm not sure why you would want to use `systemd` module instead of `service` - the latter should cover CentOS 6 and 7 without any difference.

Also use an arithmetic comparison for `ansible_distribution_major_version` instead of the string comparison as in your example.

---

Handlers listening to topics:

```yaml
---
- name: restart apache on 7
  systemd: name=httpd state=restarted
  when: ansible_distribution_major_version >= 7
  listen: "restart apache"

- name: restart apache on 6
  service: name=httpd state=restarted
  when: ansible_distribution_major_version < 7
  listen: "restart apache"
```

and the task notifying them:

```yaml
- name: Copy custom configs
  copy:
    dest: /etc/httpd/conf/
    src: httpd.conf
    owner: root 
  notify: "restart apache"
```